# What is the fifth digit from the left of $12345678987654321\times625$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> We have been calculated $$12345678987654321\times625$$
>
> Then what is the fifth digit from the left of this number?

I can rewrite it as  $$12345678987654321\times625={\underbrace{111111111}_{9\text{times}}}^2\times25^2=(111111111\times20+111111111\times5)^2=(2222222220+555555555)^2=2\underbrace{77777777}_{8 \text{times}}5^2$$
But I can't find fifth digit from the left of this square number.

Comment: $12345678987654321\cdot 625=7716049367283950625$, so what is the problem? It is $0$.

Comment: Well, you only care $\pmod {100}$ so this is just $111^2\times 25^2\pmod {1000}$.  Not so bad.

Comment: @lulu Fifth digit from the left. Wouldn't your comment work only if it was fifth digit from the right?

Comment: @ACheca  Ah, missed that.  Yes, in that case one can't do it my way.

Comment: Notice $12345678987654321 \times 625 = 123456789876543210000 / 16$. 
To get the fifth digit, you need to figure out the last digit of $\lfloor \frac{1234567}{16}\rfloor
= \lfloor 77160 + \frac{7}{16}\rfloor = 77160$ which is $0$.

Comment: $0.625=\frac58$. $\frac{1234567\ldots}8=154321\ldots\;$, so $\frac58\cdot1234567\ldots=771605\ldots\;$, and the fifth digit is $0$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you for the answer. I have a question, How you recognized $\frac{1234567\ldots}8=154321\ldots\;$? did you just divide $1234567\ldots$ to $8$ by hand?

Comment: @philomath: Yes; that I could do in my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $625=5^4$, we have $n\times625={n\times10000\over16}$, so it suffices to do long division of $123456789\ldots$ by $16$. This is perhaps easiest to do by dividing *twice* by $4$:

$${123456789\ldots\over4}=3086419\ldots$$

and

$${3086419\ldots\over4}=771604\ldots$$

so the fifth digit (from the left) is $0$.

The key observation is that the special nature of $625$ allows us to change an ostensibly messy multiplication problem into a relatively simple long division problem that lets us to ignore all but the first few digits of the number we're dealing with.

Answer (score 3):

For similar problems with more digits (to prevent multiplying out as easily as in this case) you could adopt the following method.

$123456 \times 625 = 77160000$

$123457 \times 625 = 77160625$

So the answer is $0$.